# Make $_SESSION["logged_user"]="" instead of Destroying Sessions in Sign-out page

Tags: php, session

I need to display different content for logging users and others. So I make that part as following code.

```
<?php 
            if($_SESSION["logged_user"]=="")
            {
                ?>        
                <div id="test">Display for un-logged users</div>        
                <?php
            }
            else
            {
                ?>        
                <div id="test>Display for Logged Users</div>        
                <?php
            }
?>
```

I **can't destroy all sessions** in **sign-out page** because of I use "$_SESSION["logged_user"]" in every page.

So I make sign-out page like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["logged_user"]="";
?>
```

**I just empty the $_SESSION["logged_user"] instead of destroying session.**

Is it a bad idea? If it is a bad idea what is the solution for me?

Comment: use unset($_SESSION["logged_user"])

Comment: @Uttam What is the difference between `$_SESSION["logged_user"]="" `and `unset($_SESSION["logged_user"])`

Comment: `unset` destroys the variable ....  Your way keeps the variable intact, just sets the value to `nothing`

Comment: and then test `if( !isset( $_SESSION["logged_user"] ) ) {/* not logged in */} else {}` etc

Comment: Thanks. It worked. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// remove all session variables
session_unset();

// destroy the session
session_destroy();
?>
```